# PostgreSQL Get orders with items

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following tables in a database,

Orders:

```
    |order_id | 
----+---------+
  1 | 123-456 |
  2 | 123-455 | 
  3 | 123-454 |
```

Order Items:

```
    |order_id |description| 
----+---------+------------
  1 | 123-456 |  ABC
  2 | 123-456 |  DEF
  3 | 123-456 |  GHI
  4 | 123-455 |  ABC
  5 | 123-454 |  DEF
  6 | 123-453 |  GHI
```

What I want to do is the following:

```
SELECT o.*, array_to_json(array_agg(i.*)) as items
FROM orders o
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items i
ON i.order_id = o.order_id
group by o.order_id
```

I need to be able to select orders with items that contain a certain description, but also keep all other items in the order.

So if I did the following;

```
SELECT o.*, array_to_json(array_agg(i.*)) as items
FROM orders o
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items i
ON i.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE i.description LIKE '%ABC%'
group by o.order_id
```

I need the result to be;

```
    |order_id |items| 
----+---------+------------
  1 | 123-456 |  [{"order_id":"123-456","description":"ABC"},{"order_id":"123-456","description":"DEF"},{"order_id":"123-456","description":"GHI"}]
  2 | 123-455 |  [{"order_id":"123-455","description":"ABC"}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you don't need `o.*` then?  Because the only non-aggregated column in your desired output is `o.order_id`?

Comment: This was just an example table to get the idea across, the actual table has many more columns but were not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that your existing query basically works, I've made the following changes...

- `o.*` to `o.order_id`
- `WHERE <condition>` to `HAVING SUM(<condition>) >= 1`

This gives

```
SELECT o.order_id, array_to_json(array_agg(i.*)) as items
FROM orders o
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items i
ON i.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN i.description LIKE '%ABC%' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

Comment: Good solution. If the `orders` table has more columns and the OP is interested in seeing them too, there is nothing wrong about selecting `o.*`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Even with `GROUP BY o.order_id`?

Comment: Yes, `o.*` is functionally dependent on `o.order_id` (provided, of course this is the table's primary key, as the name suggests).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I did not know that PostgreSQL allowed that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.*, array_to_json(array_agg(i.*)) as items
FROM orders o
JOIN order_items i
ON i.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE o.order_id in(select oi.order_id from order_items oi where oi.description LIKE '%ABC%')
group by o.order_id
```

Comment: How does PostgreSQL perform with long IN lists?  My experience on other DB's is to use `EXISTS()` in preference?

Comment: Should not make any difference but you're welcome to try and compare query plans.

Comment: @MatBailie: I'm always surprised when DBMS are slow on `IN`, but not on `EXISTS`. Re-writing an `IN` clause to an `EXISTS` clause is a no-brainer, so where do those DBMS actually fail? I don't think that PostgreSQL will have a problem with this. And `IN` is often much more readable than `EXISTS`.